# Unsightly lines appearing between polygons in ggplot2 map on printed pdf but not in graphics device

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

I can't seem to get rid of lines between my polygons in ggplot2, when I print a map to pdf.  AND I can't reproduce my error either on a new dataset, in a MWE.

Here is my code for the map:

```
map <- ggplot(USA_fort_premade) + 
  aes(long,lat,group=group) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(x=long,y=lat, group=group, fill=avg_coveragelevel), 
               data=fips_fort)+
  geom_path(color="black", lwd = .1) +
  coord_fixed(1.3) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "yellow", mid = "lightblue",
                       high = "blue", midpoint = .7, 
                       space = "Lab", width = 6),
                       na.value = "grey80", guide = "colourbar") +
  theme_map()
```

`USA_fort_premade` is the outer shapefile, and `fips_fort` is the inner shapefile.  On the R graphics device, it looks fine:

[image]

when I print it to PDF, it looks like this:

[image]

It doesn't matter how I export it, and it looks the same in evince and okular -- it's not a relic of the viewer.

When I try to specify the color of the polygon border being the same as the fill, I get this, which is not what I want

[image]

I think that the difficulty has something to do with the fact that I'm overlaying one shapefile with another.

Are there any workarounds?

*OK FINE*  I made a MWE, but I can't reproduce my error!  I'm even more confused now.  Anybody know where the lines could be coming from?

```
library(maptools)
library(raster)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(broom)

theme_map <- function (base_size = 12, base_family = "") {
  theme_gray(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family) %+replace% 
    theme(
      axis.line=element_blank(),
      axis.text.x=element_blank(),
      axis.text.y=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.length=unit(0.3, "lines"),
      axis.ticks.margin=unit(0.5, "lines"),
      axis.title.x=element_blank(),
      axis.title.y=element_blank(),
      legend.background=element_rect(fill="white", colour=NA),
      legend.key=element_rect(colour="white"),
      legend.key.size=unit(1.2, "lines"),
      legend.position="right",
      legend.text=element_text(size=rel(0.8)),
      legend.title=element_text(size=rel(0.8), face="bold", hjust=0),
      panel.background=element_blank(),
      panel.border=element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
      panel.spacing=unit(0, "lines"),
      plot.background=element_blank(),
      plot.margin=unit(c(1, 1, 0.5, 0.5), "lines"),
      plot.title=element_text(size=rel(1.2), vjust = 2),
      strip.background=element_rect(fill="white", colour="white"),
      strip.text.x=element_text(size=rel(.8), margin=margin(b=3)),
      strip.text.y=element_text(size=rel(0.8), angle=-90) 
    )   
}


Kaz_shp <- getData('GADM', country='Kazakhstan', level=1)
fips_shp <- getData('GADM', country='Kazakhstan', level=2)
fips_shp$plotvar <- runif(nrow(fips_shp@data))

Kaz_fort <- tidy(Kaz_shp, region = "NAME_1")
fips_fort <- tidy(fips_shp, region = "NAME_2")
fips_fort <- merge(fips_fort, fips_shp@data[,c("NAME_2","plotvar")], by.x = "id", by.y = "NAME_2")

map <- ggplot(Kaz_fort) + 
  aes(long,lat,group=group) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(x=long,y=lat, group=group, fill=plotvar), 
               data=fips_fort)+
  geom_path(color="black", lwd = .1) +
  coord_fixed(1.3) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "yellow", mid = "lightblue",
                       high = "blue", midpoint = .7,
                       space = "Lab", name = "wowee wow",
                       na.value = "grey60", guide = "colourbar") +
  ggtitle("Potassium Production")+theme_map()
map
dev.copy2pdf(file = "verynice.pdf")
system("evince verynice.pdf")
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Probably your pdf viewer app. Read up on anti-aliasing. Whatever the problem you need more details about OS, viewer and the underlying data.

Comment: @42- thanks, it's not that.  I checked both Okular and evince

Comment: If you haven't produced a MWE, then you can probably benefit from thinking a little bit more about your problem. See if you can reproduce the behavior in another context. "My files are large" and "I don't see an obvious example on the internet to copy" just means you have to think about it a little more.